# Does AWS Lambda (Java API) support JSR-250 annotations?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lifecycle, aws-lambda

Is there a way to register startup and shutdown hooks in an AWS Lambda Java function, either via standard JSR-250 annotations (`@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy`) or some other means?  Obviously, I can use a zero-args constructor or an instance initialiser for the startup side of things, but I'm interested to know if there's a better way.. an interface in the API that I'm missing perhaps - I certainly don't want to use a `finalize()` method for the shutdown hook!

As a bit of background, the use case here is for initialising and closing down a `KafkaProducer` instance which we'll use to send messages to a topic based on incoming DynamoDB table events.

**Update**

The Lambda best practices encourage writing stateless function classes - so my assumption is that there is *intentionally* no support for startup / shutdown code. In that model I guess we will need to create and close any resources required on each invocation of the handler event.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda is intended to be used as stateless infrastructure, but it will also reuse the same "container" under some circumstances, but you want to make sure you understand how this works before you make your application depend on this.

With AWS Lambda using Java, this means that you can have a singleton class that is able to initialize once per container.  This pattern allows for performing initial setup of the container such as loading files from S3 once or establishing a connection to another server such as Kafka, MySQL, Memcached, etc. (Side note: only servers on the public internet can be connected to at this time, but connecting to servers in VPCs is an announced feature that is coming soon.)

AWS Lambda will always deploy new containers when you deploy a new version of code so during these times you will likely see the most turnover in active containers.  Also, after a period of inactivity AWS Lambda will shutdown idle containers.  However, if you have a consistent stream of requests your AWS Lambda container will be reused for multiple requests.

The specific behaviors of how containers are reused is not described in detail by AWS as far as I can tell.  This is likely because the whole point of AWS Lambda is that you do not need to worry about the infrastructure anymore.

As for receiving a signal to do additional processing when the container is shutting down, I do not believe there is a way to do this right now.  The intent of Lambda is that you are only billed for your requests and shutting down occurs outside of that window.  Obviously the containers do eventually get terminated, but I'm not aware of the details of what actually happens to terminate the JVM are documented right now.

---

Related to your specific concerns about a KafkaProducer, you most likely will need to wait for AWS to release additional features to better support this use case.

A discussion of concerns with connection poll exhaustion related to AWS Lambda outlines a related issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216000

Comment: Thanks - bit of a 'watch this space' one at the moment then.. might post something on the AWS dev forums too regarding best practice for maintenance of client connections to external services (like kafka).

Comment: Are there any new insights regarding this?